# How to get all children without the parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
Transform[] drawns = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()
```

This include also the parent but i want to get only the children of the transform the script is connected.

The problem is that it's destroying in the loop also the parent.
The first item in the array of drawns is the parent :

```cs
case DrawStates.DrawOnGizmosRuntime:
drawOnce = true;
if (line != null && drawOnGizmos == false)
{
    Transform[] drawns = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    if (drawns.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (Transform drawn in drawns)
        {
            Destroy(drawn.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
if (boxCollider == null)
{
    boxCollider = boxColliderToDrawOn.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
}
drawOnGizmos = true;
break;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually several ways to find children without parent.

```cs
foreach (var child in children) Debug.Log(child);
```

---

**Use Where extension:**

After using `system.linq`, you can separate children that are not the original transform, as shown below.

```cs
var children = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().Where(t => t != transform);
```

---

**Removing index 0:**

Since index 0 is always the main transform, you can delete it after converting children to list.

```cs
var children = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().ToList();

children.RemoveAt(0);
```

---

**Using Skip(1)**

Thanks to dear @Enigmativity, Another solution is to use `Skip(1)`, which actually avoids the main transform member.

```cs
var children = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().Skip(1);
```

Comment: It seems like `transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().Skip(1).ToList();` would be a good choice too.

Comment: This is a great answer, but the only thing that bugs me about it is that the Unity documentation does not specify that the parent transform will always be the first entry. It's true right now, but it's incidentally true, and could change at any time with a Unity update.

Comment: As a clarification, I'm referring to GetComponentsInChildren. We know how it works, but there's no promise that it will always work the same way. I mean maybe they'll find a way to speed it up with AVX-512, and the order control will go out the window. You never know.